# How and Why AWS bill comes after i suspended the account

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

Could you please help me about the Billing system of AWS.

I suspended my aws account last month that time my account bill is $900 but today I got the message that your aws account bill is $1200 . How it is possible.

Comment: [Why did I receive a bill after I closed my AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/closed-account-bill/)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not have a "suspend" account. You can close an account. If you are using resources in AWS you will be charged for them.

If you feel that your bill is in error, contact Amazon Billing department. Go to this page and select "I'm an AWS customer and I'm looking for billing or account support". In my experience they are very easy to work with.

[AWS Billing Support](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)

[EDIT - credit to @James Thorpe's comment]

[Why did I receive a bill after I closed my AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/closed-account-bill/)